# fancybox - not to load hidden images

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

On my website i have multiple galleries which are being opened with FancyBox. Structure is: show one photo from gallery, and when you click it fancybox opens and you navigate through photos from that gallery in fancybox modal.

Code is: main photo is showed

```
<li><a id="some_id" class="grouped_elements" rel="some_rel" href="some_href"><img src=""></a></li>
```

And then photos with same attribute "rel" which are "belonging" to that gallery:

```
<li><a id="some_id" style="display:none;" class="grouped_elements" rel="some_rel" href="some_href"><img src=""></a></li>
```

On photos that belong to that gallery i put "display:none;" so they are not displayed on page, but only when you open fancybox by clicking on main photo.

This works, but problem is i have lot of photos and page loading is really long, so is there way to prevent photos with "display:none" from loading, to make it load after some gallery is opened?

EDIT: forgot to mention, i am using fancybox 2.1.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using an AJAX call to fetch the gallery/images the user requests. This will be asyncronous and will not affect the page loading. Once a succesfull response is received, you can then initilise the $().fancybox() using the response data

Answer (score 0):

Your solution can be much simpler:

Wrap all your anchors in a hidden `div` instead hiding them individually and remove the `<img>` tag from all the hidden anchors, in that way you are not loading any (big) image regardless is visible or not so :

Main photo shown :

```
<li><a id="some_id" class="grouped_elements" rel="some_rel" href="some_href"><img src=""></a></li>
```

Hidden photos

```
<div style="display:none">
    <a id="some_id" class="grouped_elements" rel="some_rel" href="some_href"></a>
    <a id="some_id" class="grouped_elements" rel="some_rel" href="some_href"></a>
    ... etc.
</div>
```

**Notice** that you don't even need to wrap them inside a `<li>` tag and that `div` can placed anywhere in your document and outside the `<ul>` element.

**Two additional comments**:

1. Make sure that you are not repeating the same ID in several elements. IDs should be unique within the same document. If you want to manipulate several elements using the same selector within the same document, use *classes* instead.
2. Make sure that you are using resized images for your thumbnails (`<img>` tag); re-sizing a big image to look small like a thumbnail via css or html is not (generally) a good idea.